# Is there any way to see the Custom Layout applied to the Action Bar in the Android Studio Layout Editor?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-layout-editor

Assuming you did not modify any properties in style.xml, the Layout Editor in Android Studio displays the Action Bar as:

[image]

By adjusting the style of the action bar, I can do things like adjust the background color of it.

However, the ActionBar I use is a Toolbar that uses a custom layout that can not be expressed simply by adjusting the properties of the action bar, as shown below.

[image]

It is not difficult to apply the above layout to the Action Bar during runtime. (change custom view, or apply AppTheme to NoActionBar, then set SupportActionBar)

What I really want is that the AppBar with these custom layouts will print out all of the xml inside the project I'm working on, but I have not found the right answer for it so far.

Is this an operation not supported by the Android studio?

Comment: I am unable to understand what you actually want,update your question

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via ToolBar & FrameLayouts,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            //TextView
            //ImageView
            // etc

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</FrameLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize">
</FrameLayout>
```

Organize your host activity layout as above and load fragments inside the main_container